# Inline Block element with width auto doesn't update

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I am having trouble with inline-block elements with

```
width: auto;
```

and programatically changing the height with javascript.

Here is a jsFiddle that demonstrates it;

http://jsfiddle.net/uJZjB/2/

The idea is that if you resize your window, the javascript sets the elements' height, and the inline-block element's width automatically adjusts to fit the content.

However, the width does not auto update and it remains at the original width rather than resizing to match the width of the content.

If you cause the dom to refresh by hiding and showing the element, or changing the display style e.t.c. the widths are updated!

Please see this modified jsfiddle;

http://jsfiddle.net/uJZjB/5/

This one on chrome, now forces the width:auto; to kick in and work, on Firefox it still appears not to update.

Is there a reason why the widths wont update when set this way?

Regards,

Comment: What width are you expecting it to be set to?  Inline-block elements shrink down to *the size of its children*.

Comment: If the number of your elements is fixed, you can assign to `width` the percentage calculated on the number of your elements. For example, you have 4 elements, then set `width: 25%;` and the elements will update their width automatically.

Comment: I am expecting the width to match the width of the 100% height image that is inside the li. For some reason, if you refresh the display style, it re-sizes the li to match the width of the image inside. I do not want to programatically set the width as width:auto; should size to the children.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the width of the elements alongside the height to what would be expected with `width:auto` by taking the width of the children:

```
$('#myul li').css('width',$('#myul li').children().width() + 2); // compensate for border
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uJZjB/4/

Comment: Thanks! I would prefer not to programatically set the width as my issue is with width:auto not working as expected and this does not really solve the issue.